# menu tab not becoming active in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, tabs

Here the menu tabs are not becoming and don't know why it seems look like this.Here is the control please have a look

```
public function vehicle($id=NULL)
{
    if (!empty($id)) {
        $data['active'] = 2;
        $this->Vehicle_model->_table_name = "tbl_vehicles"; //table name
        $this->Vehicle_model->_order_by = "id";
        $data['vehicle_info'] = $this->Vehicle_model->get_by(array('id' => $id), TRUE);

    } else {
        $data['active'] = 1;
    }
    $data['all_vehicle_info'] = $this->Vehicle_model->view_vehicle(null,null);
    $this->load->view('admin/vehicle/add_vehicle',$data);

}
```

here is the view

```
<ul class="tabs rs-tab">
    <li class="<?php echo ($active == 1) ? "active" : ""; ?> tab col s3 "><a href="#manage" >All Vehicles</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo ($active == 2) ? "active" : ""; ?> tab col s3"><a href="#create" >New Vehicles</a></li>
  </ul>
<div class="<?php echo ($active == 1) ? "active" : ""; ?>" id="manage" >
</div>



<div class="<?php echo ($active == 2) ? "active" : ""; ?>" id="create">
</div>
```

Comment: are you getting $active ?

Comment: yaa am getting $active value while doing var_dump

Comment: In view file right?, because I had pasted your tab code with static $active , it works

Comment: `echo $id` see what you get. If nothing try uri segments https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html#CI_URI::segment

Comment: I also try this code in my local with static variable. Your code works fine. you need to check css or jquery side.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 yaa $id is passing the value

Comment: @JigarShah yaa in view file also the correct value is passing

Comment: Then it may be css issue

Comment: am working in material design will it be

Comment: guys.. i got it...just gave the active class to the anchor tag and removed from <li> tag